# Debugging what uWSGI worker is doing

Tags: python, django, debugging, uwsgi

I have a Django application (API) running in production served by uWSGI, which has 8 processes (workers) running. To monitor them I use uwsgitop. Every day from time to time one worker falls into the BUSY state and stays for like five minutes and consumes all of the memory and kills the whole instance. The problem is, I do not know how to debug what the worker is doing at the particular moment or what function is it executing. Is there a fast and a proper way to find out the function and the request that it is handling?

Answer (score 0):

One can [send signal SIGUSR2](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html#signals-for-controlling-uwsgi) to a uwsgi worker, and the current request is printed into the log file, along with a native (sadly not Python) backtrace.